# Dynamic HTML title tag

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html

I want to create a dynamic HTML title (INPUT). I now do this using the contentblockbyID function:

```
<title>%%=ContentBlockbyId("123456")=%%</title>
```

In the content block I have the following AMP code:

```
%%[

var @titel_tag
set @titel_tag = AttributeValue("A")

if @titel_tag == "B" then
]%%
Title dynamic based on trigger data.
%%[ elseif @titel_tag == "C" then ]%%
XX
%%[ else ]%%
 Your notification
%%[ endif ]%%
```

This works, however instead of only showing the piece of text, a piece of HTML code is placed around it likt this:

```
<title><table role="presentation" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner">
'Titel dynamisch. Gebasseerd op de trigger.'
</td></tr></table></title>
```

How can I make sure this doesn't happen?

Comment: use a code snippet block

Comment: You mean the %%=ContentBlockbyId("123456")=%% as snippet or the content block itsself? I want to keep the AMP code outside the email for easily editing purposes in the future.

Comment: What @EazyE is referring to is the type of block in Content Builder.  Using HTML or Free Form injects extra HTML that the Code Snippet type does not.

Comment: Ah yes. That did the trick. Thanks for helping.